# Really, really simple jQuery that doesn't work :(

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Seriously. The simplest jQuery code ever simply isn't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.codeswitcher').click(function() {
        alert("You clicked it");
 });

});
</script>
```

And then, in my page structure, I have this:

```
<div class="codeswitcher">
<img src="http://mysite.com/images/codeswitcher.png" alt="codeswitcher">
</div>
```

It's just a 32x32px image. And you can click it. But nothing happens! :( I've also changed my jQuery selector to `.codeswitcher img` and `div.codeswitcher`, but still nothing.

I have other jQuery code also running on the page just fine. What's going wrong?

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: check for any jquery conflicts !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're not crazy, your example code works: http://jsfiddle.net/c3e6X/

Check to see if you have a JavaScript error before this code runs, just open the console and look.

If it's created **dynamically**, e.g. AJAX then you should use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.codeswitcher').live('click', function() {
    alert("You clicked it");
  });
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle looks like a neat site! Thanks for confirming, by the way.

And the problem is that it was generated by Ajax. Thanks for letting me know, I didn't know you had to select it differently in a situation like that!

Comment: Can't accept your answer for another 9 minutes though... but, thanks :)

Comment: @Jack - The selector runs **at that time**, and attaches a `click` handler to the elements it found...this just wasn't there to find :)  for a bit more explanation: `.live()` listens for the event to bubble up to `document`...since new and old elements bubble events the same way, it just doesn't matter when they were added.